# How to write a condition for scanf that only accepts inputs that are integers including zero but not letters?

Tags: c

I have this scanf function:

```
scanfResult = scanf("%s%d%d", X, &LO, &HI);
```

I need to write a condition that would only accept integers in the second and third place in my scanf function (in the place where %d's are) and not any letters. I could write something like that:

```
if (HI == 0 || LO == 0){
     printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

However it than does not accepts int "0" as an input, which I want to accept. How to write a condition so that it would accept zero but not any letters? (I am a beginner)

My input is:

```
c 45 abc
```

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: You have to read it as a string and filter yourself.

Comment: In a terminal after a program is running I write some string, than space, than string, than space, than integer. I want my program to accept only integers in the second and third position.

Comment: @johnelemans How to write that? (it could be easy but I am a beginner and I really do not know)

Comment: Please show an actual input you give. Are the string and two numbers on the same line or on separate lines?

Comment: Not "some string" or "integer".  What **exactly** is your input, and how do you know it wasn't read correctly?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: start by reading everything in as a string. Then examine them one by one and see if they have legal data according to your specs. If they do, you can convert strings to numbers then.

Comment: `scanf` is difficult to use correctly, and it's difficult to use if you're trying to carefully constrain user input.  Rule 1 is to check `scanf`'s return value.  (In your case, if `scanfResult` is not equal to 3, something went wrong.)  Then, either settle for the functionality `scanf` gives you (don't try to get fancy), or, [consider alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop with getchar(). put in the code for allowed alphabet.
something like this

```
while (1)  {
   ch = getchar();
   // if ch is <enter  key > the break
   if (policyOK( ch ) ) {
      printf("%c", ch );
   } else {
       // print a beep sound or don't do anything
   }
}
```